# i want to send unique records for every user who logs in from a mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

i want to send every user who logs in a list of unique records i.e not same records from the database,
for every user i want to skip the records that have already been sent to other signed users.bare with me ,am a beginner,how can i implement such?
here is the code that fetches the records from the database

```
phrases.findAll({
      where: {
         userId: user.id,
         phraseStatus: 1
      },
      limit: 10,
      offset,
      10
   })
   .then((data) => {
      userObj.phrases.push(...data);

      return res.status(200).json(userObj);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep track of what has been sent to other users. I suggest you keep a table like `phrases_sent` to record what has been sent so far. Add the `phrase_id` to this new table so you have a relationship.

Take a look at [associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html) in the docs.

You can then query the `phrases` table by outer joining to your `phrases_sent` table to return phrases that have not been sent so far.

Something like:

```
    const phrases = await sequelize.models.phrase.findAll({
        where: {
            '$phrasesSents.phrase_id$': {[Op.is]: null} // query the joined table
        },
        attributes: ['phrase.phrase'], // the unused phrases
        include: [
            {
                attributes: [],
                model: sequelize.models.phrasesSent,
                required: false, // specify this is a left outer join
            }
        ],
        raw: true,
        nest: true
    });
```

Would yield:

```
SELECT "phrase"."phrase" 
FROM "phrases" AS "phrase" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phrases_sent" AS "phrasesSents" ON "phrase"."id" = "phrasesSents"."phrase_id" 
WHERE "phrasesSents"."phrase_id" IS NULL;
```

I believe doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN has performance benefits over a NOT IN (SELECT ...) style query.